# I get the error "Access denied" even though I own the bucket and have all perms

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to grant read only access to an anonymous user when I am hit with an "Access denied" error even though it is my bucket and I have all perms.

I have tried editing the principal to look like this:

```
"Principal": {
        "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/myuid"
        ]
```

but then I get an incomplete json error.

This is the one Amazon uses as it example which,I have edited to cater to me:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

It should make the bucket public so all can view my website but, that isn't happening because of the access denied.

Comment: Do you have the `s3:PutBucketPolicy` permission action set in you IAM?

Comment: no I do not how do I do that this is my first time using aws

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-bucket-policy/ This link will show you how to add it

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as `answered` if it resolves your question.

Comment: When do you receive the "Access Denied" error? What action are you performing?

Comment: I am trying to grant read only access to anonymous users

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to grant access to a **specific IAM User**, then you should add a policy to that IAM User (without using a Bucket Policy).

If you wish to grant access to "anyone" (without authentication), then you should create a **Bucket Policy** such as:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, be sure to turn off [Amazon S3 Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html) otherwise you will receive an `Access Denied` error when trying to access content.

Comment: How do I turn off Block Public access? I have never used json before

Comment: Click the bucket name, click Permissions tab. On "Public access settings" click Edit, then turn off both options under "Manage public bucket policies for this bucket".

Comment: "If you wish to grant access to "anyone" (without authentication), then you should create a Bucket Policy such as: "thats an example of IAM policy, bucket policy requires principle in it.

Answer (score 0):

You IAM policy for should have `s3:GetBucketPolicy and s3:PutBucketPolicy` set as permission actions on the IAM account.

Your policy should look like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ExampleStmt",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
        "s3:PutBucketPolicy"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can view a trouble shooting doc here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-bucket-policy/